# Грамотно ли будет использовать словосочетание "адекватное интервью"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Хотелось бы узнать, насколько грамотно использование словосочетания "адекватное интервью". Применила его на одном сайте в отзыве на интервью врача. Врач переболел коронавирусом и описывал то, что ему удалось осмыслить по поводу этой болезни. Подразумевала,что содержание интервью соответствует требованиям текущей ситуации. При этом исходила из того, что фактически использую разговорную речь (сайт не научный, а новостной). Участники комментариев упрекнули в речевой ошибке.

Comment: "**Адекватный** — вполне соответствующий чему-л. (условиям, обстановке и т.п.)" (толковый словарь Кузнецова). Но Вы бы лучше привели цитату, а то вряд ли кто захочет не глядя подписаться под её правильностью.

Answer (score 1):

Речевую ошибку можно усмотреть в отсутствии зависимых слов: интервью,  адекватное **чему** (какой ситуации, событиям и т. п.)? Если опустить такие слова, пусть и в разговорной речи, слово "адекватный" приобретает значение психиатрического термина: из области, изучающей "адекватность" поведенческих реакций  (соответствие их реальности и предсказуемость у психически здорового человека) в бытовую речь перекочевало понятие "адекватный (неадекватный) человек  или индивид", ставшее дипломатичным вариантом ссылки на "вменяемость-невменяемость".

В вашем контексте, расценив интервью как "*(просто) адекватное*", вы невольно противопоставили его интервью, которое дал бы "неадекватный" (=не вполне вменяемый, безумный) человек. В результате получился сомнительный комплимент уважаемому доктору: "да, это было интервью вменяемого человека (а не сумасшедшего)". Поскольку вы никого не хотели обидеть и имели в виду другое (информативное, уместное к случаю интервью), то слово употреблено не совсем удачно.

Comment: Точно, первая ассоциация